# Using try catch in watch of Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a textarea. I'am coding an object. I want to control this data that is available for syntax. My html code is:

```
<b-form-textarea
   id="textarea-state"
   v-model="data.deviceData"
   :state="codingControl == true"
   rows="8"
 />
```

I'm coding this below object in my `b-form-textarea` component.

```
{
   "device_id":"",
   "outputs":[false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false],
   "inputs":[false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]
}
```

And I watch this object is available for syntax or not. But `try catch` can not catch the error. How can I catch this error, if that object has a syntax error?

```
watch: {
   data: {
      handler(val) {
        try {
          this.datas = JSON.parse(val.deviceData)
          this.codingControl = true
        } catch (error) {
          this.datas = JSON.parse(val.deviceData)
          this.codingControl = false
        }
      },
      deep: true,
    },
}
```

By the way watch is runnig. single problem `try catch` can not run.

Comment: What happens if you throw something dumb like `'2'.yolo()` in the line just after the `try` ? That way, it should be caugth in the `catch`.

Comment: It will go into `catch` if it catches an exception, you can do that manually by using `throw` in your `try` block as shown here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#unconditional_catch-block

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/dyNNabo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whats probably happening is this:

```js
watch: {
   data: {
      handler(val) {
        try {
          this.datas = JSON.parse(val.deviceData)    // Step 1: Lets say this throws an error
          this.codingControl = true
        } catch (error) {                            // Step 2: Error get caught here
          this.datas = JSON.parse(val.deviceData)    // Step 3: Same invalid data is being parsed, so it will throw an error again 
          this.codingControl = false                 // Step 3.5: It never reaches here because the code above threw an error
        }
      },
      deep: true,
    },
}
```

Comment: you absolutely all right. I realized my mistake right now. Thank you :)